# Is there any differences between an array defined by "getValues()" and simple declaration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing a script to import some data into GoogleBigQuery. In order to do this I need to grab some data from my spreadsheet and "record" them as a csv.

However in between, I want to add some new values derived from my original spreadsheet.

so here is my main script which is working fine :

```
    function test_export() {

<-- BigQuery code here not related to the issue -->

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
      var filename = spreadsheet.getName();

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw_data");
      var Row_count = sheet.getLastRow();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      var csvdata = "";
      for (var row = 1; row < data.length && row < Row_count + 1; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {  
        var punctRE = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
        var spaceRE = /\s+/g;
          var cell = data[row][col].toString();
              Logger.log(cell)


          if (cell.match(/http/g)) {
            var cell = data[row][col].toString();
          } else {
            var cell = data[row][col].toString().replace(punctRE, '').replace(spaceRE, ' ');
          }

          if (cell.indexOf(",") != -1) {
            csvdata += "\"" + cell + "\"";
          } else {
            csvdata += cell;
          }

          if (col < data[row].length - 1) {
            csvdata += ",";
          }
        }
        csvdata += "\r\n";
      }

      var data = Utilities.newBlob(csvdata, "application/octet-stream");

      // Execute the job.
      BigQuery.Jobs.insert(jobSpec, projectId, data);
    }
```

The output of `data` (`var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`) is  `[[data1,data2,data3,etc...],[data1,data2,data3,etc...]]`

Now, here is the change I've done  when trying to add some new derived values :

```
      var raw_data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var data = []

  for (var i = 0; i < Row_count ; i++) {
    data.push([raw_data[i].toString()])
    data.concat(raw_data[i][5].toString().split("?")[0])}
```

I've simply renamed the original `data`(`var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`) `raw_data`. I've declared a new array `data`. I'm pushing in this array all the rows more one derived value with the concat method.

So the output of `data` is still `[[data1,data2,data3,etc...],[data1,data2,data3,etc...]]`

However when doing `Logger.log(cell)` I don't have the same behaviour between my first and my second script. Why is that ?

Comment: You don't have `cell` defined anywhere above. What's the log difference?

Comment: `var cell = data[row][col].toString();` in the for loop in the integral code.

Comment: Would you post the whole loop as well as the Logger difference? Still hard to tell what problem you're having. If the final arrays are equivalent, I don't see where the difference would be.

Comment: the whole loop is already posted is the main script. I didn't change the last part of the script so I only post the modified part for the second script I'm using. But I maybe should rewrite my question. It doesn't seems clear enough.

Comment: I feel like this code can be made simpler for the sake of debugging, if I understand correctly the BigQuery part here is not really relevant as the issue appears before?

Comment: This is correct syntax for concat `data = data.concat(raw_data[i][5].toString().split("?")[0])`. Concat does not modifiy the orginal array, you have to explicitly define it. Also, I am not sure what do you plan to achieve use concat, add to the pushed data points? In that case, the syntax needs to include a index of where to concat like  `data = data[i].concat(raw_data[i][5].toString().split("?")[0])`